# Displaying list on HTML page from view in Django

Tags: python, django

I've got a list in my views.py which I'm sending to a HTML page via the render function and I'm printing it out on that page. Problem is that, while all other lists that I send are getting printed on the HTML page, these 2 lists I'm sending in particular are not.

**app/views.py**

```
alttrue = []
altfalse = []
alttrue, altfalse = altCheck(soup)
results = { 'alttrue' : alttrue,
            'altfalse' : altfalse,
          }
render(context,'app/result.html', results)
```

Now altCheck is a function that returns two lists where at least one of them have values, that's for sure. In my result.html,

**results.html**

```
<h5>Alt pass results</h5>
{% for tag in alttrue %}
<p>{{ tag }}</p>
{% endfor %}
<h5>Alt fail results</h5>
{% for tag in altfalse %}
<p>{{ tag }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that running a for loop through the list and trying to print it, returns an empty list ([]). However, If I were to try and print it as such

```
<p>{{ alttrue }}</p>
<p>{{ altfalse }}</p>
```

It works fine. It prints the list. Just, iterating the list and printing out the variables doesn't work.

Comment: In one, you use `altfalse` and in the other you use `altpass`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, your render should look like `render(request, template_name, context)`. It's not clear to me what your `context` variable is. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Answer (score 0):

Here is whats going wrong:

```
alttrue = []
altfalse = []
alttrue, altfalse = altCheck(soup)
results = { 'alttrue' : altpass,
            'altfalse' : altfail,
          }
render(context,'app/result.html', results)
```

in the result dict the variable in under quotes (key) is suppose to be name of context variable. This should look like below

```
alttrue = []
altfalse = []
alttrue, altfalse = altCheck(soup)
results = { 'altpass' : alttrue ,
            'altfail' : altfalse ,
          }
render(context,'app/result.html', results)
```

template.html

```
{% for x in altpass %}
{{x}}
{% endfor %}

{% for x in altfail %}
{{x}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Haha, no no. That was my typo. It's actually named fine. The problem is not in the naming. When I display the list as a whole it works. When I run a loop through the items of the list and try to display, it doesn't work. Have edited again. My mistake.